# How can I delete decimal points from a 'double' type to later be displayed as a currency?

Tags: c++, string, math, double, rounding

I am currently building a mock banking app that can display the history of transactions on an account.

Part of a transaction is, naturally, the amount.

Amounts are stored as doubles in my program which leads to many of them being displayed with way too many decimal points (for example £500.000000 instead of £500.00).

When forming a transaction, the amount is simply converted to a string alongside timestamps and transaction types.

I need a way so that the double can be stored without the extra decimal places. It doesn't matter if it is converted to two decimal places before or after becoming a string.

I cannot use setprecision(2) here because I am not writing out the transaction to the console yet.

```
Transaction::Transaction(string desc, string timestamp, double value) {

    this->desc = desc;
    this->timestamp = timestamp;
    this->value = value;
};

string Transaction::toString() {
fullString = "-- " + desc + ": -\x9c" + to_string(value) + " on " + timestamp;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `double` data for money. Use a large integer type and base units of cents or pennies.

Comment: You can use a `std::stringstream`, which has the same functionality as `std::cout`, but stores everything into a buffer.

Comment: The standard way is to count in cents, and **add** a decimal point when displaying the amount.

Comment: *I need a way so that the double can be stored without the extra decimal places.*. This is simply not possible.  The number of decimal places is established by the definition of *double* - the Wikpedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format is a reasonably good place to take your research next.

Comment: The way to delete decimal points is to not put them in to begin with. Use an integral type for currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this helper function:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string value2string(double value)
{
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << value;
  return out.str();
}

string Transaction::toString() {
fullString = "-- " + desc + ": -\x9c" + value2string(value) + " on " + timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use setprecision(2) here because I am not writing out the transaction to the console yet.

Yes you can use it. Just use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::string Transaction::toString() {
    std::ostringstream fullString;
    fullstring << "-- " << desc << ": -\x9c" << std::setprecision(2) << value << " on " << timestamp;
    return fullString.str();
}
```

If you use C++20 or later you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)